# In the simplified shell program, the program uses two arrays of chars, as shown below (in the code userin.c)

Tags: c, exec, computer-science, pid, unistd.h

```
static char inpbuf[MAXBUF], tokbuf[2 * MAXBUF],
        *ptr = inpbuf, *tok = tokbuf;
```

The array `inpbuf` is intended to store the user typed command and
its arguments. The array `tokbuf` is intended to store each extracted tokens from inpbuf,
such that, each element in the array `char *arg[MAXARG + 1]`; (in `proc_line.c)` is properly
assigned using the information in `tokbuf` in order later on to invoke `execvp` system call in
`runcommand.c`

I just want to get rid of `tokbuf` used in `userin.c` and make the program work can someone help me

userin.c

```
#include "smallsh.h"

static char inpbuf[MAXBUF], tokbuf[2 * MAXBUF],
*ptr = inpbuf, *tok = tokbuf;

int inarg(char c);

int userin(char *p)
{
    int c, count;
    ptr = inpbuf;
    tok = tokbuf;
    
    printf("%s", p);
    count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if ((c = getchar()) == EOF)
            return(EOF);
        if (count < MAXBUF)
            inpbuf[count++] = c;
        if (c == '\n' && count < MAXBUF)
        {
            inpbuf[count] = '\0';
            return count;
        }
        
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            printf("smallsh: input line too long\n");
            count = 0;
            printf("%s ", p);
        }
    }
}

int gettok(char **outptr)
{
    int type;
    
    *outptr = tok;
    
    while (*ptr == ' ' || *ptr == '\t')
        ptr++;
    
    *tok++ = *ptr;
    
    switch (*ptr++) {
    case '\n':
        type = EOL;
        break;
    case '&':
        type = AMPERSAND;
        break;
    case ';':
        type = SEMICOLON;
        break;
    default:
        type = ARG;
        
        while (inarg(*ptr))
            *tok++ = *ptr++;
    }
    *tok++ = '\0';
    return type;
}

//****************************************************************************************
static char special[] = { ' ', '\t', '&', ';', '\n', '\0' };
int inarg(char c)
{
    char *wrk;
    for (wrk = special; *wrk; wrk++)
    {
        if (c == *wrk)
            return (0);
    }
    return (1);
}
```

runcommand.c

```
#include "smallsh.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int runcommand(char **cline, int where)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    switch (pid = fork()) {
        case 1:
            perror("smallsh");
            return (-1);
        case 0:
            execvp(cline[0], cline);
            perror(*cline);
            exit(1);
    }
    //code for parents
    if (where == BACKGROUND)
    {
        printf("[process id %d]\n", pid);
        return (0);
    }
    
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1)
        return (-1);
    else
        return (status);
}
```

Comment: `userin` never uses `ptr` or `tok`, and never calls `gettok()`. It looks like `userin()` is just replicating what `fgets()` does.